# How can I get my changes to css to actually show up?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use css to make changes to my resume, but the changes aren't applying. I've tried using Live Preview in the Brackets code editor and by opening the file directly using firefox. I have linked the stylesheet to my html document. Here's my css:

```css
body {
  font-size: 4px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.position {
  float: left;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

.company-dates {
  float: right;
  line-height: 0.8em;
  text-align: right;
}


/* Custom, iPhone Retina */

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 320px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 4px;
  }
  .contact-right {
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 4px;
  }
  .contact-right {
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
}


/* Small Devices, Tablets */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}


/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}


/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Redacted</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container header">
    <h1>Redacted</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="contact-left col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>(919)-397-8116</p>
        <p>Github: <a href="Redacted" target="_blank">Redacted</a></p>
        <p>Redacted</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-right col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>Redacted</p>
        <p>Redacted</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h5><b>Summary</b></h5>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;Team player software engineer with open-source, frontend, backend, and management experience. I make others around me better through excellent communication and a purely constructive attitude. You should hire me because I have a passion
      for making cool stuff that makes people’s lives better and the broad technical aptitude to do it.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h5><b>Objective</b></h5>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;Seeking a full-time position in Software Development for an innovative company that will help me specialize my skills. I have a vast foundation that allows me to learn new things quickly and want experiences that will help me deepen my
      skillset.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="overflow: auto;">
    <h5><b>Education</b></h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="education-left col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>&emsp;&emsp;Redacted</p>
        <p>&emsp;&emsp;B.S., Computer Engineering May 2017</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container professional-experience">
    <h5><b>Professional Experience</b></h5>
    <div>
      <div class="" style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="position">
          <p><u>QA Lead</u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="company-dates">
          <p>Redacted</p>
          <p>December 2017 – April 2018</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="position-information">
        <li>Led a team of 3 offshore and 1 local Test Engineers in Quality Control, the Software Test Life Cycle, Automation best practices, Team Communication, and Time Management</li>
        <li>Introduced and Documented a new effort in website test automation using Snaptest</li>
        <li>Initiated a system of code reviews and a deployment plan throughout the company</li>
        <li>Developed 10 automated test scripts for API endpoints in Go and numerous others in Postman using Javascript</li>
        <li>Created over 75 automated tests for websites across various projects in Snaptest</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="position">
          <p><u>Developer/Project Manager</u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="company-dates">
          <p>Redacted</p>
          <p>April 2017 – December 2017</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="position-information">
        <li>Developed a base API framework and production-ready endpoints in Go</li>
        <li>Designed the Bluetooth LE communication scheme for a mobile application to a custom proprietary IOT healthcare product in C</li>
        <li>Led 3 teams of developers across 3 projects in multiple platforms, 2 of which were from start to completion</li>
        <li>Created a Unity demo project with lightsabers for the Meta 2 Augmented Reality headset</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="position">
          <p><u>Software Development Student</u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="company-dates">
          <p>Redacted</p>
          <p>Aug. – Dec. 2015</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="position-information">
        <li>Delivered solutions for 14 software defects and 2 user stories using Java on Android</li>
        <li>Contributed to team-wide software integrity using a peer code review process in Gerrit</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="position">
          <p><u>Software Test Student</u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="company-dates">
          <p>Redacted</p>
          <p>Aug. – Dec. 2014, May – Aug. 2016</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="position-information">
        <li>Documented 51 unique software issues in a Scrum development cycle</li>
        <li>Scripted automated test suites for several user stories in RIDE, spanning hundreds of test cases</li>
        <li>Developed an Excel macro that parses thousands of user reviews for keywords and trends</li>
        <li>Seamlessly Transitioned between 3 mobile operating systems and 2 separate applications</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container various-technical-experience">
    <h5><b>Various Other Technical Experience</b></h5>
    <ul class="position-information">
      <li><b>Golang/Open Source:</b> Contributed to the alexa-skills-git-golang and go-jira Github open-source repos</li>
      <li><b>XHTML/CSS:</b> Built a version of this resume using XHTML/CSS</li>
      <li><b>PHP:</b> Personal websitethat interfaces with the OMDB movie search API</li>
      <li><b>Python:</b> Personal desktop app client using PyQT4, UI creation, API utilization, Multithreading</li>
      <li><b>C:</b> Compiler design, Text autocomplete function, GPS application</li>
      <li><b>C++:</b> Team project working with a LIDAR sensor to detect and analyze objects for an autonomous vehicle – used OpenCV and Visual Studio</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is that changes such as `font-size: 20px;` in the `@media (min-width : 1200px)` breakpoint aren't working. I don't see any change in the document. I've tried changing the min-width to max-width in the breakpoints, but that did nothing. I also thought it might be the breakpoints themselves not working, so I put the `body` tag up at the top to apply to all sizes and still nothing. I just get the generic font-size=14px; that's standard for bootstrap. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you attempted a hard refresh at all (ctrl + f5) on the page, then changed the size of your window to see if they're taking effect? Also move your personal css link to below the bootstrap style sheet link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always link your custom stylesheet after(below) bootstrap css link.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Redacted</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <!-- 
  *
  * Remove the css codes below and place them in the style.css file linked exactly above these lines if you need to use an external css
  *
  -->
  <style>
    body {
      font-size: 4px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .position {
      float: left;
      line-height: 0.8em;
    }
    
    .company-dates {
      float: right;
      line-height: 0.8em;
      text-align: right;
    }
    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */
    
    @media (min-width: 320px) {
      body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        min-width: 320px;
        line-height: 1.0em;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 4px;
      }
      .contact-right {
        line-height: 0.8em;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
    
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 1.0em;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 4px;
      }
      .contact-right {
        line-height: 0.8em;
        text-align: right;
      }
    }
    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 1.0em;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    }
    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    }
    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container header">
    <h1>Redacted</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="contact-left col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>(919)-397-8116</p>
        <p>Github: <a href="Redacted" target="_blank">Redacted</a></p>
        <p>Redacted</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-right col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>Redacted</p>
        <p>Redacted</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h5><b>Summary</b></h5>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;Team player software engineer with open-source, frontend, backend, and management experience. I make others around me better through excellent communication and a purely constructive attitude. You should hire me because I have a passion
      for making cool stuff that makes people’s lives better and the broad technical aptitude to do it.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h5><b>Objective</b></h5>
    <p>&emsp;&emsp;Seeking a full-time position in Software Development for an innovative company that will help me specialize my skills. I have a vast foundation that allows me to learn new things quickly and want experiences that will help me deepen my
      skillset.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="overflow: auto;">
    <h5><b>Education</b></h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="education-left col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>&emsp;&emsp;Redacted</p>
        <p>&emsp;&emsp;B.S., Computer Engineering May 2017</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container professional-experience">
    <h5><b>Professional Experience</b></h5>
    <div>
      <div class="" style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="position">
          <p><u>QA Lead</u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="company-dates">
          <p>Redacted</p>
          <p>December 2017 – April 2018</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="position-information">
        <li>Led a team of 3 offshore and 1 local Test Engineers in Quality Control, the Software Test Life Cycle, Automation best practices, Team Communication, and Time Management</li>
        <li>Introduced and Documented a new effort in website test automation using Snaptest</li>
        <li>Initiated a system of code reviews and a deployment plan throughout the company</li>
        <li>Developed 10 automated test scripts for API endpoints in Go and numerous others in Postman using Javascript</li>
        <li>Created over 75 automated tests for websites across various projects in Snaptest</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="position">
          <p><u>Developer/Project Manager</u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="company-dates">
          <p>Redacted</p>
          <p>April 2017 – December 2017</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="position-information">
        <li>Developed a base API framework and production-ready endpoints in Go</li>
        <li>Designed the Bluetooth LE communication scheme for a mobile application to a custom proprietary IOT healthcare product in C</li>
        <li>Led 3 teams of developers across 3 projects in multiple platforms, 2 of which were from start to completion</li>
        <li>Created a Unity demo project with lightsabers for the Meta 2 Augmented Reality headset</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="position">
          <p><u>Software Development Student</u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="company-dates">
          <p>Redacted</p>
          <p>Aug. – Dec. 2015</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="position-information">
        <li>Delivered solutions for 14 software defects and 2 user stories using Java on Android</li>
        <li>Contributed to team-wide software integrity using a peer code review process in Gerrit</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="overflow: auto;">
        <div class="position">
          <p><u>Software Test Student</u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="company-dates">
          <p>Redacted</p>
          <p>Aug. – Dec. 2014, May – Aug. 2016</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="position-information">
        <li>Documented 51 unique software issues in a Scrum development cycle</li>
        <li>Scripted automated test suites for several user stories in RIDE, spanning hundreds of test cases</li>
        <li>Developed an Excel macro that parses thousands of user reviews for keywords and trends</li>
        <li>Seamlessly Transitioned between 3 mobile operating systems and 2 separate applications</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container various-technical-experience">
    <h5><b>Various Other Technical Experience</b></h5>
    <ul class="position-information">
      <li><b>Golang/Open Source:</b> Contributed to the alexa-skills-git-golang and go-jira Github open-source repos</li>
      <li><b>XHTML/CSS:</b> Built a version of this resume using XHTML/CSS</li>
      <li><b>PHP:</b> Personal websitethat interfaces with the OMDB movie search API</li>
      <li><b>Python:</b> Personal desktop app client using PyQT4, UI creation, API utilization, Multithreading</li>
      <li><b>C:</b> Compiler design, Text autocomplete function, GPS application</li>
      <li><b>C++:</b> Team project working with a LIDAR sensor to detect and analyze objects for an autonomous vehicle – used OpenCV and Visual Studio</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- First move the line linking your css after the bootstrap one, otherwise the bootstrap styling will take effect because it comes in later. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`
- Second: Add !important to your font size styling (eg.: `font-size: 24px !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the min's to max. Think of it as 'how big can this screen get?'

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media (max-width : 320px)
```

Comment: Also see @Horacio Coronel's comments. Your css should definitely be after bootstrap's.